# Unifi Controller Centos7 Stop Work

Tags: centos

Unifi Controller on CentOS 7 Stop working after is running after 2-3 days

I have this error on mongodb log

got signal 15 (Terminated)

f -h output:

https://termbin.com/i7dj

MondoDB LOG:

https://termbin.com/swo7

this is Server Log

https://termbin.com/c3sz

I repair mongodb database but the problem remain after 2-3 days unificontroller stop work

---

i repair mongodb database but the problem remain after 2-3 days unificontroller stop work

---

df -h output:

https://termbin.com/i7dj

MondoDB LOG:

https://termbin.com/swo7

this is Server Log

https://termbin.com/c3sz

Answer (score 0):

Please send more information. Run **df -h** and see if you are out of disk space.

If you have plenty of disk space, try.

> mongod --repair

You might have to add some parameters for this to work.  Drop in a larger part of the mongodb log so we can see more details.

Comment: i try to repair mongod this is the output:

https://pastebin.com/kS98sk9F